# How Spring Boot run batch jobs

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-boot

I followed [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-batch/src/main/java/sample/batch/SampleBatchApplication.java) for Spring Batch with Boot.

When you run the main method the job is executed. 
This way I can't figure out how one can control the job execution. For example how you schedule a job, or get access to the job execution, or set job parameters.

I tried to register my own JobLauncher

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepo){
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepo);
    return simpleJobLauncher;
}
```

but when I try to use it in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);    
    JobLauncher jobLauncher = ctx.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    //try catch removed for readability
    jobLauncher.run(ctx.getBean(Job.class), new JobParameters());   
}
```

The job is again executed when the context is loaded and I got `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException` when I try to run it manually. 
Is there a way to prevent the automatic job execution?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The jobs execution can be prevented by setting

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

in application.properties. Or you can use `spring.batch.job.names` it takes a comma-delimited list of job names that will be run.

Taken from here: [how to stop spring batch scheduled jobs from running at first time when executing the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318907/how-to-stop-spring-batch-scheduled-jobs-from-running-at-first-time-when-executin)

Comment: I tried spring.batch.job.enabled=false and also running the jar with java sys properties -Dspring.batch.job.enabled=false still it execute the job. How it debug it, I have no clue

Comment: @Anuj Acharya You can ask a question about it where you can give more details about the problem(like the spring version) and share some code.

Comment: Sorry Evgeni, I have created a seprate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276011/spring-boot-spring-batch-job-enabled-false-not-able-to-recognize

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the execution of a Job using rest controller POST:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/job/")
public class JobLauncherController {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(JobLauncherController.class);

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

    @RequestMapping("/launchjob/{jobName}")
    public String handle(@PathVariable("jobName") String jobName, @RequestBody Map<String,Object> request) throws Exception {
        try {           
            request.put("timeJobStarted", DateUtil.getDateFormatted(new Date(), DateUtil.DATE_UUUUMMDDHHMMSS));
            Map<String,Object> mapMessage = this.enrichJobMessage(request);
            Map<String, JobParameter> jobParameters = new HashMap<>();
            mapMessage.forEach((k,v)->{
                MapperUtil.castParameter(jobParameters, k, v);
            });
            jobParameters.put(Field.Batch.JOB_INSTANCE_NAME, new JobParameter(jobName));
            jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters(jobParameters));
            assertNotNull(jobRegistry.getJob(job.getName()));
        }catch( NoSuchJobException ex){
            jobRegistry.register(new ReferenceJobFactory(job));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }

        return "Done";
    }

public static void castParameter(Map<String, JobParameter> jobParameters, String k, Object v){
    if(v instanceof String){
        jobParameters.put(k, new JobParameter((String)v));
    }else if(v instanceof Date){
        jobParameters.put(k, new JobParameter((Date)v));
    }else if(v instanceof Double){
        jobParameters.put(k, new JobParameter((Double)v));
    }else if(v instanceof Long){
        jobParameters.put(k, new JobParameter((Long)v));
    }else{
        DslJson dslJson = new DslJson<>();          
        JsonWriter writer = dslJson.newWriter();
        try {
            dslJson.serialize(writer,v);
            jobParameters.put(k, new JobParameter(writer.toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
        }                       
    }
}

}
```