# Spring boot spring.batch.job.enabled=false not able to recognize

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I tried `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` in application.properties and `-Dspring.batch.job.enabled=false` when running the jar file.

However `@EnableBatchProcessing` automatically start running the batch jobs on application start. How i can debug such scenario?

**TestConfiguration.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class TestConfiguration {...}
```

**MainApplication**

```
@ComponentScan("com.demo")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MainApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) throws BeansException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException, InterruptedException, JobRestartException {

ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(TestConfiguration.class, args);
...}
```

**pom.xml**
I am using dependency as spring boot and not as parent

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Import dependecy for spring boot from here-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to know whats going on, I am using custom reader/processor/writer. When springboot application starts it actually try to do dependency injection of this custom beans beans where I have written some application logic.

Example

** TestConfiguration.class**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @Conditional(Employee.class)
        public ItemWriter<Employee> writer_employee(DataSource dataSource) throws IOException {
            FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<Employee>();
            writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(FinanceReportUtil.createFile("Employee.csv")));
            writer.setHeaderCallback(new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {
                @Override
                    public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
                    writer.write("id, name");
                 }
             });
            DelimitedLineAggregator<Employee> delLineAgg = new DelimitedLineAggregator<Employee>();
            delLineAgg.setDelimiter(",");
            BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Employee> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Employee>();
            fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[]{"id", "name"});
            delLineAgg.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
            writer.setLineAggregator(delLineAgg);
            return writer;
        }

        @Bean
        @Conditional(Manager.class)
        public ItemWriter<Person> writer_manager(DataSource dataSource) throws IOException {

            // Does the same logic as employee
        }

        // Also has job and step etc.
    }
```

It will create the file even with spring.batch.job.enabled=false, to overcome this I have created custom logic to inject the beans or not as below

**application.properties**

```
# all, manager, employee
person=manager
```

**ManagerCondition.class**

```
public class ManagerCondition implements Condition {

@Override
public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    String person= context.getEnvironment().getProperty("person");
    return person.equals("manager");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, the property 'spring.batch.job.enabled=false' was not recognising at start up when we give this in properties file. It could be because the properties might not have loaded into context before the batch initiated.

So i have set the property 'spring.batch.job.enabled=false' in standalone.xml as a system property like below.

```
<system-properties>  
        <property name="spring.batch.job.enabled" value="false"/>  
</system-properties>
```

With this it SUCCESSFULLY worked & the spring batch jobs did not initialised on server start up.

Please note that the system-properties must be placed right after the extensions tag in standalone.xml.

Comment: +1 for giving me the hint about the properties not being loaded. I had defined a custom "batch.properties" file where I had disabled the automatic execution of the jobs, but I hadn't included that property file with `@PropertySource`! :|

Answer (score 0):

You can put debug breakpoint in a  read() method in your Reader then Step Out of that method to trace what method call read(), keep going you will find the method launching the batch job.

```
@Component
public class ActSpeedSubTaskReader implements ItemReader<ActSpeedTask> {

  

  @Override
  public ActSpeedTask read()
      throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
   // put the breakpoint here
   // read here
    return null;
}
```