# Spring Boot and Batch: Stop batch from starting based on application.properties value

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Boot application.  When my application starts up I have to seed the database.  After that I don't need to seed it again.  As of now, I'm doing this using Spring Batch.  But the batch kicks off any time I start my app (dev-test-redeploy).

Is there a way for me to tell Spring Batch to do nothing based on a variable?  I know how to get my environment parameters anywhere they need to be, I just don't know where to put it in my Spring Batch setup.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447948/how-spring-boot-run-batch-jobs: `enabled=false` and start your job programmatically

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Thanks Luca.  That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your full setup is, but is it possible to check the database (do a simple count) to see if the data is already there in your `Step`/`TaskLet` implementation to not process the items at all or your reader/writer to just skip the items?

If you really want to use a configuration property, you may want to take a look at applying a `@ConditionalOnProperty` to your batch configuration. (Although using a property is more prone to human error, as you need to remember to toggle the parameter the second time you start the app).